# Are using the adverbs gradually and greedily to describe the same verb contradicting?

Tags: creative-writing, style, word-choice

For example, the man eats greedily, gradually, with no hesitation

Comment: Hi, welcome to writing.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information. This question is off-topic here but you might have better luck over at [english.se]. Make sure to review their guidelines before posting!

Answer (score 2):

As commonly understood, "gradually" and "greedily" suggest completely opposite paces. "Greedily" implies quickly, or with an urgency to complete the task. It just doesn't go with "gradually", it causes cognitive dissonance.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is an awful use of the English language. However, one adverb does not contradict the other. One verb refers to speed whilst the other refers to volume (excess).

"Gradually, the politicians greedily increased their pay and benefits."

- That's not great either.